# How might 'to play the flute' have evolved to mean 'flout'?

Tags: etymology, middle-english

> [flout (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=jeer&searchmode=none) [<--] "treat with disdain or contempt" (transitive), 1550s, intransitive sense "mock, jeer, scoff" is from 1570s; of ***uncertain*** origin; ***perhaps*** a special use of Middle English *flowten* **"to play the flute"** (compare Middle Dutch *fluyten* "to play the flute," also "to jeer"). [...]

Please expose and explain all (possible or conjectured) (hidden and missing) semantic drifts and links. What is a right way of interpreting the etymology, to understand how the semantic jumps might've abstracted and severed from the original literal meaning?

I already read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flute#Etymology) and the OED’s [brusque entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71993?rskey=c3Fwtw&result=4#eid).

PS:  Etymonline listed the above under the etymology for [jeer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=jeer&searchmode=none), my original research goal.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not exactly sure that it did.

Comment: @ScotM Thanks; I ought to have asked about the **surmised or conjectured** semantic drifts and links.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flout and other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glynnis Chantrell, *The Oxford Dictionary of Word Histories* (2003) has this entry for flout:

> **flout** {mid 16th century} This is perhaps from Dutch *fluiten* 'whistle, play the flute, hiss (in derision)'; German dialect *pfeifen auf*, literally 'pipe at', has a similar extended meaning.

Julia Cresswell, *The Insect That Stole Butter? Oxford Dictionary of Word Origins*, second edition (2009) doesn't add much to Chantrell's coverage:

> **flout** {M6th} Flout, which appeared in the 16th century and means 'to openly disregard a rule or convention', may come from a Dutch word *fluiten* meaning 'whistle, play the flute, hiss derisively'. There is a German Dialect expression *pfeifen auf*, literally 'pipe at', which is used in a similar way. Flout is often confused with **flaunt** {M16th}, 'to display something ostentatiously', but there is no connection—the origin of flaunt is unknown.

Eric Partridge, *Origins: A Short Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1966) discusses *flautist*, *flute*, and *flout* under a longer entry for *flabellate* and allied words:

> **flabellate** (whence **flabellation**), **flabellum**; **flageolet**; **flautist**, **flute**; **flout** (v hence n).
>
> 1. The base is L *flāre*, to blow, *flō*, I blow, s[tem] and r[oot] *flā*-: ...
>
> ...
>
> 3. E *flautist*, flute-player, derives from It *flautista* (It-L agential *-ista*), from It *flauto*, flute, from Prov. But E flute, ME floute, floite, comes from EF-F *flûte*, OF-MF *flaüte*, *fleüte*, OF *flehutes*, from Prov *flaut*, itself—though influenced by Prov *laut* (see musical LUTE)—from Prov *flaujol* ...; like OF-MF *flajol*, OProv *flaujol* perh derives from VL *flabeolum*, but is prob echoic,as indeed *flajol* may be.
> 4. OF-MF *flaüte*, *fleüte* have derivatives *flaüter*, *fleüter*, EF-F *flûter*, whence ME *flouten*, *floiten*, to play the flute, whence 'to *flute*'. Now ME *flouten* prob yields also 'to *flout*' to mock: cf. D *fluiten* (from the OF v), orig to play the flute, but derivatively to jeer.

Ernest Weekley, *An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1921) seems far less confident about the derivation, however:

> **flout.** ? ME. *flouten*, to play the flute; cf. Du. *fluiten*, to humbug. Very doubtful, as *flout* expresses a much stronger idea.

---

I'm not sure what to make of the idea that derisive hissing in the Dutch sense of *fluiten* was originally directed *at* flute players or flute playing, rather than being equated *with* them because of the similarly high-pitched sound. In much of the world, whistling is used as a way of expressing contempt for a performance or (in sports) a disputed ruling by a referee—and yet there is no obvious reason to suppose that the practice originated as a form of derision directed at people playing tin whistles.

The sound of whistling or fluting or piping (presumably related to the English idiomatic expression "Pipe down!") can be piercing and shrill, and it readily suggests a human vocal equivalent that lends itself to use in situations where the person making the sound wants to express disapproval of something—loudly. That's one possible explanation for how flute playing and sounds expressing ridicule came to share a root word.

On the other hand, the historical opprobrium associated with flute playing—as detailed in ermanen's answer and Peter Shor's comment is not to be taken lightly or dismissed casually as a possible influence on the development of *flout*. No wonder the history of *flout* remains unsettled.

Comment: +1. Thanks. More about 'pipe down' here: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/283600.html

Answer (score 1):

It might be derived from the practice of playing a flute to ridicule in olden times. It is mentioned in the book *The Flute Book: A Complete Guide for Students and Performers* by Nancy Toff:

> The verb *flaut* (to jeer or mock) is related to the Middle English spelling of flute, and **apparently derives its meaning from the practice of playing a flute to ridicule.**
>
> The word *flute* is derived from the Provençal *flauta*, which in Middle English and Old French became *flaute, flahute*, or *flahuste*. The modern Spanish *flauta* and Italian *flauto* are direct descendants of the Provençal, while modern French took a divergent path toward *flûte*. **The earliest English spellings of the modern flute are *flowte* and *floute* (Chaucer, 1384), pronounced *floot;floyte* (Caxton, 1483), pronounced *floo-eet*, as in Louis; and *flutes* (Eden, 1555).**

*(emphasis mine)*

Comment: Searching the net briefly, I discovered that in the Middle Ages, they made people [wear a flute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_humiliation#Shameful_exposure) to ridicule them. Maybe that's where *"flouting"* came from.